# gdb - get the real line of crash

Tags: c++, gdb

My multithread program crash. I have `.core` file. I load it and `thread apply all backtrace` and get the following output for thread that crashed:

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x8567800 (runnable)):
#0  GG::serialize (this=0x847c180, outbin=@0xbf2f7c30)
    at basic_string.h:269
```

Ok, crash while serializing, but reported that its occur at `STL basic_string.h:269`.

But how to get actual line of crash at `serialize()` function?

Comment: Going up the call stack works for me. I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to debugging, however.

Comment: @chris what you do? or look at whole info reported by `thread apply all backtrace`. I skip there lines at my example, because next line reported about previous function before `serialize()`. But I want more information what is going on at `serialize()` line of code or socking else. I serialize `3` `std::string` 's at this function, but can not understand why its crashed time to time....

Comment: Well, I use CodeBlocks, so it's pretty easy. Usually it might go something like `my function > some lower level function > some lower level one > crash` and all I have to do is scroll up to where I see my function, then it highlights/goes to the crashing line in *my* code. That's sometimes all the information you need to figure out why it crashes. Without something like that, I'm not sure.

Comment: @chris thanks, but its IDE and also I can not use it because program works at the remote freebsd machine (i have only ssh console). About `my function > some lower level function > some lower level one > crash` - yes. I know its `serialize()` then -> crash.. but where at `serialize()` I does not know and want to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the crash is reproducible, the easiest thing to do is to recompile the faulty code with inlining disabled (in `g++`, this is `-fno-inline` and `-fno-default-inline`).

If you have to analyze the core you have, try to find what method in `string` was being invoked, and find the corresponding call in your `serialize` function.

Sometimes, there is no other way to find the problem other than to disassemble your function and walk through it a bit to find which parts of the assembly code correspond to your source code. Then, to figure out the values of the local variables, you have to do `info registers`, and track what values were moved into what register.

Comment: Yes, its hard, but I can reproduce it.I am null at assembler :(